# Using CSV file with Bash

Tags: bash, csv

Looking to use a csv file that uses headers as variables that change at each line but I want to do something simple like run a `while read -r` or For loop off each line. During the loop I want each entry to be that specific variable. For instance, generating csr files.

CSV would be something like:

```
server alias cn san environment
server1,srv1,srv1.domain.com,"dns:srv1.coolstuff.org,dns:srv1.morecoolstuff.org:,production
server2,srv2,srv2.domain.com,"dns:srv2.dev.coolstuff.org,dns:srv2.dev.morecoolstuff.org",development
```

and so on... would run through

keytool -gen blah blah for each line using the entries

Anyone have any ideas. I know there 8000 ways to skin a cat.

Comment: The header line seems to be missing commas, and the first line of the data has a quoted field that lack terminating double quote. Please specify exactly what the "blah blah" bit of your command is.

Comment: Please add a raw example input file and an example output one

Comment: sorry yeah.. there is a missing quote in the dns: line.... I just want to use the variables at each line to run a keytool command against them... it would be something like (also using the other variables) keytool -genkey \
                -alias $ALIAS \
    -keyalg RSA \
                -keysize 2048

Comment: please just [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/622261/edit) the question, rather than adding more info (or correcting errors) in the comments.

Comment: please add both input and output example text you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i usually use `csvtool` for dealing with CSV-files in bash-scripts.

something like this should do:

```bsh
csvtool namedcol server,alias,cn,san,environment input.csv \
| csvtool -u TAB drop 1 - \
| while IFS=$'\t' read -r server alias cn san environment; do
   echo "server: ${server}"
   echo "alias: ${alias}"
   echo "cn: ${cn}"
   echo "san: ${san}"
   echo "environment: ${environment}"
   # do something with it...
   keytool -genkey -alias "${alias}" -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
done
```

the first invocation of `csvtool` outputs the columns in the CSV file according to their name, just in case the order of columns is not fixed.

the 2nd invocation gets rid of the CSV-headers and does some delimiter mangling (using "\t" instead of `,`, just in case your input data may contain commas, but not tabs.

we then use the same delimiter in the `read` invocation using the `IFS` envvar; and use `read` to assign values to the variable names.

Comment: This makes sense... so this is just identifying the headers (variables) and then dropping down a line... so I would be able to run a command against those variables at each line

Comment: i've updated the code to use your `keytool` invocation example (i didn't check whether this invocation actually makes sense ;-))

Comment: Thank you... skipping down to line 3 and running vs. doing each line and generating a .csr for each... but it is working from a header standpoint.

Comment: if it works for you, please *accept* the answer (that's also to keep other volunteers focused on questions that have no answer yet)

Comment: working through it. right now I have 3 lines (1st line being the header)... It only runs for the last line.

Comment: shouldn't that syntax drop down to every line in the csv file? It appears to only hit the last line no matter how many lines I have in the csv file.

Comment: either your CSV-file is broken (not unheard of), or you made some typo when copying the code.

Comment: good old CSV... Appreciate it.

Comment: This seems to fail if any CSV cell is empty, i.e. `,,`. To resolve this, change `TAB` and `\t` to a different character, e.g. a pipe: `'|'`.